# Rmarkdown: Different formats for code and output with .css

Tags: css, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I can include something like

```
<style>

code {
  font: 12px Monaco, "Courier New";
  color: #969699;
}

</style>
```

in a .css file to format my code in Rmarkdown. The problem is that the R output also inherits this font. Is there any way to give my code and the R output different fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R source code in rmarkdown HTML output is placed between a `<code>` tag that lives inside a `<pre>` with class `r`. You want to apply the style to all instances of `<code>` that *don't* share this property. Here's an example using the `:not()` selector:

```css
pre:not(.r) code {
  font: 12px Monaco, "Courier New";
  color: red;
}
```

For `bookdown` output formats you want to exlcude instances of `<code>` with class `sourceCode`:

```css
code:not(.sourceCode) {
  font: 12px Monaco, "Courier New" !important;
  color: red !important;
}
```

Note that the use of `!important` is required here because the default styles have precedence.